# Why are there two plugins declarations in galleriffic.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add my own feature to `galleriffic.js` that will change a `<div>` containing text as it changes images.

The trouble is, I'm having a hard time figuring out the code. One of the main things that is confusing me is how on line 16, it contains the plugin declaration

```
$.galleriffic = {.....
```

and on line 88, it has the function

```
$.fn.galleriffic = function(settings) {...
```

What is really the difference between these two? Why not put the function inside the plugin declaration? 
Why have one that is a prototype and one that isn't? (by the `.fn`)

[Link to Gallerific Code](https://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/source/browse/trunk/example/js/jquery.galleriffic.js?r=8)

Answer (score 0):

I thnk the first declaration allows you to write:

```
$.gallerific.goto(hash);
```

This looks like some kind of convenience function.

The second declaration is for:

```
$(selector).gallerific({
    // options
});
```